# Microsoft Access SQL Editor - Enable Scroll Wheel

Tags: microsoft-access, mouse-wheel

In the Microsoft Access 2003 SQL Editor, I want to use my mouse scroll wheel.

However, the only way the program seems to allow me to navigate is via keyboard.

How do I enable scroll wheel support in the Microsoft Access SQL editor?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm too lazy to fire up A2007 or A2010 to check, but I think that's one tiny thing that was finally fixed. I could be wrong, though -- I do all my programming in A2003.

Comment: Thanks, David; anyone else have A2007 or A2010 to confirm?

Comment: I just fired up A2007, and, yes, the scroll wheel works properly in the VBE.

Comment: Ugh, how can you stand the built in Access SQL editor? From what I remember it is utter rubbish; no syntax highlighting or indenting, no ability to change the font (doesn't it use a non-monospaced font?), etc. Gross.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs have to be written to support the scroll wheel (handle the WM_MOUSEWHEEL window message).  If a program doesn't support it, the best you could hope for is a tool to map the scroll wheel to arrow keys or page up/down.